How do Animists prepare Staves?
Animists (War of Immortals, p11) are both prepared and spontaneous spellcasters. How can they prepare Staves?
Do they expend slots to add charges, or expend slots to reduce the charges needed? Do they choose every day, or can do both?

Animists are Prepared Casters for Items and Effects
This is described under Animist Spellcasting (War of Immortals, p13):

You are a prepared spellcaster for the purposes of
determining how you interact with staves and other
items or effects that differentiate between prepared and
spontaneous spellcasters.

